# Tar Gzip Every n Files in a Directory

Tags: command-line, tar, gzip

I have a folder with 7,491 files in it. I'd like to tar gzip these in batches of 100, e.g.

```
first 100 files > archive1.tar.gz
files 101-200 > archive2.tar.gz
files 201-300 > archive3.tar.gz
```

Is there a way to do this via the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest option might be to use the `split` command in combination with `find` and `tar`'s `-T`/`--files-from` option:

```bsh
find ... -type f -print0 | 
  split -t '\0' -l 100 -d --filter 'tar czf archive-$FILE.tar.gz --files-from=- --null'
```

`split` will also take care of setting filenames with sequential numbering (the `-d` option sets numbered filenames instead of the usual alphabetic ones).

With a combination of `find` and `xargs`, I couldn't find a way to get reliable sequential numbering of the archives, so I used `uuidgen`:

```bsh
find <directory> -type f -print0 | xargs -n 100 -0 sh -c 'tar -czf archive-$(uuidgen).tar.gz "$@"' _
```

Or you could use bash loops:

```bsh
count=1
N=100
find <directory> -type f -print0  | 
{
while true
do
    files=()
    for ((i=0;i<N;i++))   # Add N filenames to the `files` array
    do
        IFS= read -d '' -r file
        files+=("$file")
    done
    ((count++))
    tar -czf archive-$count.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
done
}
```

An assumption in all these commands is that `find` is not being run in the current directory. Otherwise, you might end up tarring a tar file. If you have to run it in the current directory, then I suggest saving the filenames to a file and then reading the filenames from that file for `split`/`xargs`/the loop.

Comment: What if each batch has many many files (say, 100,000)?

Comment: @Stan the `-T`/`--files-from` option would be best in that case. Maybe something like `find ... -print0 | split -t '\0' -l 100000 --filter 'tar czf archive-$FILE.tar.gz --files-from=- --null'`

Comment: Verified. Good solution!

Comment: For anyone who finds `split` lacks the `-t` option, may try `find target_path -type f | split -l file_number_per_package -d --filter 'tar cvf PackageName-$FILE.tar --files-from=- --null'`